# Call componentDidMount() manually even if component is already mounted

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-component

I have a class Dashboard component which fetch data from multiple API's in `componentDidMount()` with props received from route and renders a charts.

```
    componentDidMount() {
        this.urls = ChartProps[this.chart].api;
        this.title = ChartProps[this.chart].titles;
        
        Promise.all(
                    urls.map(url =>
                    fetch(url)
                    .then((res) => res.json())
                    .catch(error => console.log('There was a problem!', error))
                ))
                .then((json) => {
                    this.formatJsonForChart(json);
                });
        
    }
```

Now there are different props from different routes get received on same component.

```
    <BrowserRouter>
        <Navlist/>
        <Routes>
            <Route path="/" element={<Dashboard element={<Dashboard chart='chart1'/>} />} />
            <Route path="/chart2" element={<Dashboard chart='chart2'/>} />
            <Route path="/chart3" element={<Dashboard chart='chart3'/>} />
            <Route path="/chart4" element={<Dashboard element={<Dashboard chart='chart4'/>} />} />
            <Route path="*" element={<ErrorPage />} err='404' />
        </Routes>
    </BrowserRouter>
```

All the API's that fetches a data are based on received props. The problem here is function that renders a chart get called in componentDidMount() so it works fine on first route click. But when clicked on other route it doesn't call `componentDidMount()` since component is already mounted so charts doesn't get updated get clicked on other route.

What alternate approach can be taken?

Comment: Yes because `componentDidMount` will be called just on first render. Have you tried to use `componentDidUpdate`? Take a look at https://dev.to/cesareferrari/how-to-use-componentdidupdate-in-react-30en

Comment: I dint try it. But was with no state check condition. It worked..

Comment: Well I'm happy that is working BUT remember that this function will be called an huge amount of time and in several prjoect I had was the root cause of performance issues... So use it but with a lot of care =)

Comment: Thanks @GiovanniEsposito , any better alternative?

Comment: No problem. No I have no other alternatives because I think `componentDidMount` is the correct way but must be programmed in a smart way (for example, componentDidMount complete signature is `componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState, snapshot)` so you could check if prevProps are different from current props and only in this case call the fetch, in this case you avoid to call the fetch every time component will be updated).

Answer (score 0):

You could abstract the logic in your `componentDidMount` lifecycle method into a function that is called in both `componentDidMount` and `componentDidUpdate` lifecycle methods.

***OR***

Provide a unique React key to each `Dashboard` component so when the route changes React will unmount/remount a new instance.

```
<BrowserRouter>
  <Navlist/>
  <Routes>
    <Route
      path="/"
      element={<Dashboard key="/chart1" chart='chart1'/>}
    />
    <Route
      path="/chart2"
      element={<Dashboard key="/chart2" chart='chart2'/>}
    />
    <Route
      path="/chart3"
      element={<Dashboard key="/chart3" chart='chart3'/>}
    />
    <Route
      path="/chart4"
      element={<Dashboard key="/chart4" chart='chart4'/>}
    />
    <Route path="*" element={<ErrorPage />} err='404' />
  </Routes>
</BrowserRouter>
```